# Ubuntu: Fake ip address

Tags: networking, ip, redirection

I have a software package which is hard-coded to open a connection to a certain local IP address. Unfortunately, the local network settings have changed, And I can't access the source code (long story).

Is there a way - like ssh tunneling - to redirect a certain ip address to another?

For example, my software would contact `192.168.1.100`, which will be redirected to `192.168.1.15`, a real address on another machine, in a transparent way.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colleague of mine introduced me to [iptables](http://iptables-tutorial.frozentux.net/other/iptables.html):

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.100 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.15
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a static route for the server IP to the server's real IP on the client.  Add the server IP address as a subinterface on the server.

```
server# ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.100

client# route add -host 192.168.1.100 gw 192.168.1.15
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the server IP as a subinterface on the server.  Add another IP in that network to the client machine as a subinterface.

This assumes they are currently on the same network.

```
server# ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.100

client# ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.101
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the way to go:

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.100 dev eth0
```

That simply adds an IP address to `eth0`

Comment: in which machine?

Comment: @Udi, good question: if one could assign the target machine that extra IP address (if not used elsewhere to start with) then I guess this would be the same as reverting back to the old local network settings, which I assume does not work for you. In other words: I don't think you can use this (unless you actually need 192.168.1.100 to refer to localhost, which you don't).